What makes $y(x) = \log_{x}{\frac{x + 1}{2}}$ un-inversible?
So, I have a function $y(x) = \log_{x}{\frac{x + 1}{2}}$, and have a task to find an inverse $x(y)$ of it.
Here is how I approached it. First I swapped $x$ and $y$ for my comfort.
$$ x = \log_{y}{\frac{y + 1}{2}} $$
And did some transformations.
$$ y^x = y^{log_{y}{\frac{y + 1}{2}}} $$
$$ y^x = \frac{y + 1}{2} $$
$$ 2y^x = y + 1 $$
$$ 2y^x - y - 1 = 0 $$
And here I got stuck. This equation has two solutions for $y$: one trivial $\forall x\,  y(x)=1$, which doesn't fit because it results in $\log_{1}$ in the original equation, and one non-trivial. And I am unable to find the non-trivial one. I have a feeling that $y(x)$, in this case, is probably transcendental and can not be described in algebraic functions, as well as in Lambert-W, but I can't just conclude that it's unsolvable solely based on the fact I can't solve it. I need some justification why it isn't.
So, my questions are

Is it solvable?
If no, why exactly? Is there a formal way to prove it's unsolvable?
If yes, what is the solution?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

You should probably state your question as Why does [...] have no inverse?.  Or Why is [...] not invertible?  I will leave it to the professionals to say whether the second form is OK.

Your intuition is right, this is not solvable. Even for the case where $x$ is a positive integer, you're considering polynomials of degree $x$, and there is no formula for solving polynomial equations of degree greater than $4$. The cases where $x$ is not an integer or at least rational will be even further out of reach.

If $0.672438<y<1$, you could do quite nice things

One can use this general trinomial question

A function is defined from a set $A$ to a set $B$. What are $A$ and $B$ for your question?
